# Why doesn't #.# work for very small numbers?

Tags: c#

In my program, I ran into a problem writing a small number to a context.Response that is then being read by a jQuery ajax response.

```
value = -0.00000015928321772662457;
context.Response.Write(value.ToString("#.#"));
```

returns `[object XMLDocument]`

However,

```
context.Response.Write(value.ToString("n"));
```

returns 0.00 as expected.

Using "n" is perfectly fine for my program, but why did "#.#" return with an XMLDocument?

Comment: You are mixing up a variable named "result" with a variable named "value".  Clearly *result* is a number, *value* is not.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that. Value is a double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It displays a type name probably because something's `ToString()` returns `null`, so it instead has to display something else. You see similar behavior in Visual Studio's Locals panel:

1. Start a new Console Application project and replace the `Program` class:

   ```
     class Program {
          static void Main() {
               var a = new Program( "asdf" );
               var b = new Program( "" );
               var c = new Program( null );
          } // <-- breakpoint here

          string _data;
          public Program( string data ) {
               _data = data;
          }

          public override string ToString() {
               return _data;
          }
     }
   ```
2. Set a breakpoint at the closing brace (`}`) of `Main()` and run the project.
3. Now look at the Locals panel. Visual Studio tries to call `ToString()` on objects for what to display between braces in the Value column on this panel. However, because one instance returns `null`, there is evidently a fallback of getting the type name:

   ```
   a      {asdf}
   b      {}
   c      {ConsoleApplication1.Program}
   ```

I figure `context.Response.Write()` is doing something similar. Internally it uses a `TextWriter`, and here's some of the process that happens in your `"#.#"` issue:

1. `value.ToString("#.#")`, unlike `value.ToString("#.0")`, returns an empty string (`""`) because there are no non-zero digits to fill the format template (this is better than returning `"."`).
2. The `Write(string)` method of the `TextWriter` calls `ToCharArray()`, passing that on to `Write(char[])`, which of course writes nothing.

The response always produces an `XMLDocument` to the client-side, since XML is how AJAX transports requests and responses -- even the correct `"0.00"` is transported in XML. Somewhere between that and your jQuery receipt of the response, something decided an empty `XMLDocument` should be substituted when processed. Could even be jQuery itself doing that, but I don't know the ASP.NET pipeline or jQuery enough to find where.

So evidently, empty AJAX responses are not so great.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx

> By default, the return value only contains 15 digits of precision although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally. If the value of this instance has greater than 15 digits, ToString returns PositiveInfinitySymbol or NegativeInfinitySymbol instead of the expected number.

Comment: That might be what's going on, but the documentation is worded horribly.

Comment: So why does .ToString(n) work but not .ToString(#.#)? If it is precision then shouldn't both fail?

Comment: Per MSDN: "Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a significant digit, *even if zero is the only digit in the string*. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that is being displayed."